# Call method and update component between Vuejs2 multiple instances

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vuejs2

I have index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div id="appOne">
</div>
<div id="appTwo">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And 2 Vue instances in different files:

```
//appOne.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import AppOne from "./AppOne.vue";

new Vue({
    render: h => h(AppOne),
}).$mount('#appOne')
```

```
//appTwo.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import AppTwo from "./AppTwo.vue";

new Vue({
    render: h => h(AppTwo),
}).$mount('#appTwo')
```

And components:

```
//AppOne.vue
<template>
  <component-one/>
</template>

<script>
import ComponentOne from "./components/ComponentOne.vue";

export default {
  name: "AppOne",
  components: {ComponentOne}
}
</script>
```

```
//AppTwo.vue
<template>
  <component-two/>
</template>

<script>
import ComponentTwo from "./components/ComponentTwo.vue";

export default {
  name: "AppTwo",
  components: {ComponentTwo}
}
</script>
```

```
//components/ComponentOne.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button @click="foo(counter)">ComponentOne</button>
      <div>{{ label }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ComponentOne",
  data() {
    return {
      counter: 1,
      label: "default"
    }
  },
  methods: {
    foo: function (id) {
      this.label = id
    }
  }
}
```

```
//components/ComponentTwo.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button @click="updateComponentOne">ComponentTwo</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ComponentTwo",
  methods: {
    updateComponentOne: function () {
      //update componentOne.label and do some additional logic
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Question:**
Click on ComponentTwo button and in method `updateComponentOne`
update data in ComponentOne and do some additional logic

**I tried:**

1. EventBus = new Vue() and emit and subsribe on event. Result: event is received on component one but data is not updated (I guess because of `this` reference scope)
2. mitt library - same as above
3. export const state = Vue.observable(initialState), update state in component two and see how it affects computed property on component one

```
  computed: {
    someStateThatShouldBeChanged(): {
      return state.initialState
    }
  }
```

also does not work.

4. Custom Event bus, smth like:

```
class Event {
    constructor() {
        this.events = {};
    }

    on(eventName, fn) {
        this.events[eventName] = this.events[eventName] || [];
        this.events[eventName].push(fn);
    }

    emit(eventName, data) {
        if (this.events[eventName]) {
            this.events[eventName].forEach(function (fn) {
                fn(data);
            });
        }
    }
}

export default new Event();
```

Works as in the 1st case.

5. Tried to use vm variables directly:

```
export const vm1 = new Vue({
    render: h => h(AppTwo),
})
and after that tried to change data directly: 
vm1.someData = 'newValue'
```

Also does not work

I'm confused, please help me to understand why all these options do not work and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Two unrelated instance is pretty isolate and can't access to each others.

Most people in this scenario will create an instance and set `AppOne` and `AppTwo` as its components. After than you can using `$emit` to pass event to main instance from `AppTwo`'s `updateComponentOne` function and let main instance to call `AppOne` by `$refs` and change value.

But I can only assume you have your reason to keep those App isolate, but it's okay - I still have some trick can achieved it.

---

### First: merge `appOne.js` and `appTwo.js` into something like this:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import AppOne from "./AppOne.vue";
import AppTwo from "./AppTwo.vue";

const InstanceOne = new Vue({
    render: h => h(AppOne),
}).$mount('#appOne')

const InstanceTwo = new Vue({
    render: h => h(AppTwo),
}).$mount('#appTwo')

InstanceTwo.$el.addEventListener('someCustomEventName', event => {
    // // you can get custom event payload by `event.detail`
    // console.log(event.detail);

    InstanceOne.someUpdateValueFunction();
});
```

### Second: Adjust `AppTwo.vue` And `components/ComponentOne.vue` :

```js
//components/ComponentTwo.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button @click="$emit('updateComponentOne', {thisIsPayloadKey: 'thisIsValue'})">ComponentTwo</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ComponentTwo"
}
</script>
```

```js
//AppTwo.vue
<template>
  <component-two updateComponentOne="updateComponentOne"/>
</template>

<script>
import ComponentTwo from "./components/ComponentTwo.vue";

export default {
  name: "AppTwo",
  components: {ComponentTwo},
  method: {
      updateComponentOne(detail) {
          const event = new CustomEvent("someCustomEventName", { detail });
          this.$el.dispatchEvent(event);
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

## Result

Your `ComponentTwo` will trigger a `$emit` to `AppTwo.vue` and pass value you need in a object. Your `AppTwo` will dispatch a custom event to himself.

Due to we already add a event listener, so we can aware when this custom event be trigger and execute whatever we want in that event listener.

---

> updated at 2021-12-16

## Maybe you can't Merge `appOne.js` and `appTwo.js`

I saw your comment and understand your legacy might limit your option, but it's okay.

We can make `InstanceOne` and `InstanceTwo` into window :

```js
//appOne.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import AppOne from "./AppOne.vue";

const InstanceOne = new Vue({
    render: h => h(AppOne),
}).$mount('#appOne');

window.InstanceOne = InstanceOne;
```

```js
//appTwo.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import AppTwo from "./AppTwo.vue";

const InstanceTwo = new Vue({
    render: h => h(AppTwo),
}).$mount('#appTwo');

window.InstanceTwo = InstanceTwo;
```

Then set event listener in your `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div id="appOne">
</div>
<div id="appTwo">
</div>
</body>
<script src="appOne.js"></script>
<script src="appTwo.js"></script>
<script>
InstanceTwo.$el.addEventListener('someCustomEventName', event => {
    // // you can get custom event payload by `event.detail`
    // console.log(event.detail);

    InstanceOne.someUpdateValueFunction();
});
</script>
</html>
```

By add your instance into `window` will allow your instance become public. This will allow us to set listener we need in `index.html`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree that most people in this scenario will create an instance and set AppOne and AppTwo as its components. That is the key point here: I can't merge 2 Vue instances. If I would, all solutions explained in my question and in your answer worked fine. My real legacy app has more than 30 Vue instances in different files and I cant't merge them in one single file. I think the best what should be done here - redesign :)

Comment: @IgorDumchykov Hi, I provide another solution and I think this won't need you to merge any of your files. Hope this can help. Please see my update above.